# Is it safe to load collect.js async

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

Looking at the library, collect.js will take the current window._etmc array and fire off all of the current items and then continue as normal. I would assume this is to support async loading of the script. However, the documentation never specifically says it is supported and doesn't include async in the sample script snippet. Loading synchronously is causing a critical SEO performance downgrade by google. Has anyone had issues loading async?

see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_install_collect_code.htm&type=5

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is nothing wrong with firing the script asynchronously.

I would actually see this as an advantage. Usually I intentionally introduce a 3-5 second delay, from the page has loaded, and until the script fires. This is to avoid storing "false" page views, as only after being on a page for a few seconds, one can assume that content indeed has been read by the visitor.

Answer (score 1):

You can load it async by doing the following:

Add 'async' to the collect.js library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async src="http://MID.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script>
```

Then add this line in the tag:

```
var _etmc = [];
```